# why delete button keeps deleting latest row php

Tags: php

hi im trying to delete using confirmation script that connect with php , but its always deleting from the latest row that i input , im already search online how to fix it , but seems i still not really understand how it work , 
here is my code

```
    <?php 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM mspartner";
        $sql=mysql_query($query);
    ?>          
        <table class="show_data" id="partner">
            <tr>        
            <td>Partner ID</td>
                <td>Partner name</td>
                <td>addresses</td>
                <td>Image</td>
                 <td>Delete/Edit</td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
                while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            ?>
            <tr>

                <td> <?php echo $fetch['partnerID']; ?></td>
                <td style="width:100px;"><?php echo $fetch['partnername']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fetch['address']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fetch['image']; ?></td>

                <td>
                 <script>
                    function confirmation(){
                        var message = "are you sure?";
                        var konfirmasi = confirm(message);
                        if(konfirmasi == true) {
                                 window.location="index.php?delete_partner=<?php echo $fetch['partnerID']; ?>";
                        }
                        else {

                        }
                    }
                </script>
                <input type="image" class="icon" src="images/asset/delete.jpg" onClick="confirmation() ">
```

and here is my php delete code

```
             <?php 

$id = $_GET['delete_partner'];
$sql="DELETE FROM `mspartner` WHERE `partnerID` = '$id' ";
echo $sql;
$query = mysql_query($sql);
header('Location:index.php?partner');
          ?>
```

thanks for your help

Comment: You keep outputting the same function with each loop iteration. I don't think you want to be doing that.

Comment: so the wrong thing , is on the confirmation script sir ?

Comment: @user3158183: Take a look at the HTML that gets generated by this.  You'll find that you're defining the same JavaScript function over and over in the code.  Additionally, you might find some clues about the problem there.  Finally, please read up on SQL Injection in PHP.  Your code is wide open to it.

Comment: Why don't your use a `foreach` loop instead of a while loop. I don't think you're successfully iterating through the array.

Comment: @RCorrie that is the way to use the `mysql_*` functions...

Comment: @RCorrie: That kind of syntax is valid. See another example: https://eval.in/85526

Comment: @qwertynl hmm I wasn't aware of that, sorry to sidetrack but how does it work without a counter? by reference?

Comment: Huh? Counter? I have no idea what you are talking about `mysql_fetch_array` returns an array or false...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to write the confirmation js function only once at the end of the page. Much better could be to write it on a separate js file but that is another problem.
Make the confirmation function to take one parameter with the id of the record you want to delete.

Replace the code that calls the function with this:

```
onClick="confirmation('<?php echo $fetch['partnerID']; ?>')"
```

And your new confirmation function should be:

```
   function confirmation(recordId){
     var message = "are you sure?";
     var konfirmasi = confirm(message);
     if(konfirmasi == true) {
        window.location="index.php?delete_partner=" +  recordId;
     } 
   }
```

Comment: thank you so much sir , its work , ive been searching and knew there's problem with that script  , but i dunno how to fix it before , so thanks you so much sir

Comment: I do not see what the difference is between what I showed in my answer and this one, but whatever :-)

Comment: yes , there is no difference sir , :) so i thanks to both of you so much for the help

Answer (score 2):

You keep replacing your `confirmation` with a new `confirmation` function.

So whenever it runs it will only run the last iteration.

---

Try creating the confirmation function like so (by passing in the id):

```
function confirmation(id){
    var message = "are you sure?";
    var konfirmasi = confirm(message);
    if(konfirmasi) {
        window.location="index.php?delete_partner=" + id;
    }
    else {
        // something else
    }
}
```

---

Side point:

> There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: thank you so much sir , im sure will do it with mysqli next time ,, thx for your advice sir ,

Comment: @AmalMurali :-( Thanks, I just copied it from [here](https://gist.github.com/MadaraUchiha/3881905). Updating my answer now.